# How do I guarantee a certain named constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart

Let us say I have the concrete classes Cat, Dog, and Parrot, and the following interface:

```
class HasGuid {
  HasGuid.fromId(String id);
}
```

My goal is to guarantee that Cat, Dog, and Parrot all have a `fromId` named constructor. So, I can make calls like:

```
Cat.fromId("Whiskers") =returns> [A Future<Cat> object with id "Whiskers"]
Dog.fromId("Fido")     =returns> [A Future<Dog> object with id "Fido"]
Parrot.fromId("Polly") =returns> [A Future<Parrot> object with id "Poly"]
```

`fromId` is making a call across the network, for this reason I return it as a `Future`. I basically want a contract that states that any class that mixes/extends/implements/whatever the `HasGuid` class will have a named constructor of `fromId`. Where `fromId` on class `T` will take an identity string and will return a `Future<T>`.

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. A named constructor must by definition return it's own class' type, so it can't return a Future<T>.

Comment: Shoot, it was late when I wrote this, sorry. I was hopping that some combinations of factory constructor + guaranteeing interfaces might allow me to skirt around this. Short of that, a static method + guaranteeing interface would be second best.

Comment: Perhaps I should phrase it differently. I am looking for a contract that states that any concrete class A has a "class method" .fromId(String B) that returns a instance of A with the id B.

Comment: Right. Sounds like you're asking for a nice way to implement the factory pattern in Dart. I did a quick google and found this. https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/ITgz6qdyhFs/W_T0YCcnNjIJ

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that you cannot force a subclass to implement a specific named constructor ... all you can do is force the subclass to make sure the named constructor is called by the subclass.

Take for example the following ...

```dart
class Animal {
  String name;

  Animal.fromName(this.name);
}

class Dog extends Animal {

  Dog.withName(String name) : super.fromName(name);
}
```

Note the following ...

1. `Animal` has no zero argument constructor.
2. If you don't call the `super.fromName()` constructor from `Dog` you will get a compile error

```
The superclass 'Animal' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
```

3. Although `Dog` must call the `fromName()` constructor ... it doesn't have to call its named constructor the same.  In this case notice it is called `withName()`.

Answer (score 3):

There can be no assurance on constructor.

Interface(implements) assurance on instance methods.
Super class(extends) or Mixins(with) also assurance on instance methods, not constructor.

Constructor return it's own type, not a Future.

So they should all have a static method or class, but no guarantee.