# How to declare factory constructor in abstract classes?

Tags: dart

I want to declare, but not define a factory constructor in an abstract class.

In my case, I want to create a method that accepts any class that implements a `String toJson()` method as well as a `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data)` factory constructor.

Is there any way to achieve that in Dart?
I'm looking for something like the following, which is not valid Dart code:

```dart
abstract class JsonSerializable {
  factory fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data);
  String toJson();
}
```

Comment: Has there been an issue raised on the Dart Language Repo, so that they can maybe add this in future?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm afraid that it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Constructors are not part of an interface. They act more like static members.
So, you can't add a factory to the interface, and code wouldn't have any way to call the factory constructor given a type variable extending this type anyway.

So, since constructors cannot be part of interfaces, constructors also cannot be *abstract*. Being abstract simply means "make the member part of the interface, but no implementation is added to class".

You can declare the factory as a normal method, but then you would only be able to call it when you already have an instance, which likely isn't what you want with a constructor.

The only way to pass *code* around is as functions or objects with methods. So, if you want to parameterize something by a type which is `JsonSerializable`, and you want to be able to create such an object, you need to pass a factory *function* along:

```
  T deserialize<T extends JsonSerializable>(
    String json,
    T factory(Map<String, dynamic> data),
  ) {
    return factory(jsonDecode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
```

You an then call it with:

```dart
var myValue = deserialize(jsonString, (x) => MyClass.fromJson(x));
```

(If `MyClass.fromJson` had been a static function instead of a constructor, you could just write `deserialize(jsonString, MyClass.fromJson)`, but Dart doesn't yet have constructor tear-offs).

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use it?

Comment: Has there been an issue raised on the Dart Language Repo, so that they can maybe add this in future?

Comment: Any example @lrn

Comment: Constructor tear-offs have been added in 2.15 (https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a)

Answer (score 14):

As suggested in the accepted answer, I ended up creating a `Serializer<T>` type that got implemented by a serializer for each class:

[image]

Turns out, this has several benefits over just having `toJson`/`fromJson` on the classes directly:

- It decouples the serialization logic from the actual classes. That means better code readability because classes only contain methods that relate directly to the class — serializers can even be put into their own files.
- Currently, extensions can't create constructors. So having serializers separately makes it possible to write serializers for existing classes, like `String` or Flutter's `Color`, where you can't just add a `fromColor` constructor.
- Both these points combined mean it also works well with code generation — the classes are hand-written and the serializer can be generated in a separate file.

---

Code example:

```dart
class Fruit {
  Fruit(this.name, this.color);

  final String name;
  final String color;
}

// in another file

class FruitSerializer extends Serializer<Fruit> {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Fruit fruit) {
    return ...;
  }

  Fruit fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Fruit(...);
  }
}
```

An then also pass the serializer to the code that needs it:

```dart
someMethod<T>(Serializer<T> serializer, T value) {
  ...
}

someMethod(FruitSerializer(), someFruit);
final fruit = recreateFruit(FruitSerializer());
```

Obviously, you can't pass an object that can't be serialized to the code, because the method expects a `Serializer<T>`.

Comment: Do you  have an example of your `Serializer<T>` class?

Comment: Sure, for example, the `FruitSerializer` from the example above. In the `...` gaps, you'd just put the usual JSON serialization logic (`return {'name': name, 'color': color}` and `return Fruit(data['name'] as String, data['color'] as String)`).

Comment: How do your declare `Serializer<T>` class? Is there a way to make it `abstract class`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abstracted approach using Firestore DocumentSnapshot objects, where the **factory** is passed as a `Function` (reference) parameter.  *Thanks to the previous answers*

```
class User extends BaseModel {
  User({
    String? docId,
    required this.userId,
  })  : super(docId: docId);

  final String this.userId;    

  factory User.fromFirestoreDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc,) {
    final value = BaseModel.getModel(doc, User.fromJson);
    return value;
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      docId: json['docId'],
      userId: json['userId'],
    );
  }
}
```

Base Class:

```
class BaseModel {
  BaseModel({String? docId}) {
    if (docId != null) {
      this.docId = docId;
    }
  }

  String docId = 'NotSet';

  static dynamic getModel(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc,
    Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJsonHandler,
  ) {
    final json = BaseModel._getAsDocJson(doc);
    if (json == null) {
      throw Exception('No data for fromJsonHandler: $fromJsonHandler');
    }

    return fromJsonHandler(json);
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic>? _getAsDocJson(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    final json = doc.data();
    if (json != null) {
      json['docId'] = doc.id;
    }

    return json;
  }
}
```