# Dart generics class show method isn't defined for the type 'Type'

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, generics

I added fromjson method on on abstract class type T but dart shows method isnt define
here is my code
I am beginner in dart and flutter so i tried T().fromjson(data) but not works

```dart
abstract class JsonConvertable<T> {
  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}

class ProductByRemarksController<T extends JsonConvertable<T>>
    extends GetxController {

  Future<bool> loadProduct(RemarksType remarks) async {
    _isloading = true;
    update();
    try {
      final remarksUrl = ApiUrl.productByRemarks(remarks.getName);
      final response = await NetworkCaller().getRequiest(url: remarksUrl);
      for (final data in response.responseData['data']) {
        // this lines show an error
        /*
      The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
        Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJson'.
  */
        T product = T.fromJson(data);
      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using it as if it's a static method, which it's not. And unfortunately it's not possible to define static abstract methods. I'm afraid it's simply not possible. Maybe there are alternative ways to do something similar but I'm not sure how. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741737/can-one-declare-a-static-method-within-an-abstract-class-in-dart

Comment: This question also might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484370/how-to-declare-factory-constructor-in-abstract-classes

Comment: [There are many questions just like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdart%5D+t.fromjson). `static` methods and constructors in Dart are not part of a type's interface. I strongly recommend using [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and not implementing your own serialization/deserialization code. Alternatively pass around a `fromJson` callback appropriate for that type.

Answer (score 1):

you got exactly what you wanted to do and the error clearly indicates this - you can’t do that. T is a type and not an instance of the type:

```
T product = T.fromJson(data);
```

Type is just description and you can't call method on type. Instance of the type is object that is created according to this description. You should call method on type instance.

more info about [generics](https://dart.dev/language/generics) and [classes](https://dart.dev/language/classes) in dart.

Comment: "it doesn't matter what programming language we're talking about".  For Java-like generics where a single instance of the generic function/class is compiled and all type arguments must conform to a statically-known interface, yes, but for C++ templates, type substitution happens lazily at compile-time where such things would work fine.

Comment: ok, when I wrote this, I had doubts because I did not know all languages. but here I tried to emphasize the inadmissibility of such an action